# ANOVA non-normal distribution of residuals - variance estimates

Tags: anova, inference, normality-assumption

Let's assume that the normal distribution of residuals assumption is not met when we perform an ANOVA. I understand that it will probably lead to inaccurate inferential results regarding p-values and CI coverage.

But what about the within and between group variance estimates? Are they necessarily biased?

I am sorry if this topic was already discussed but I did not find my answer.

Comment: The F-statistic is the ratio  MSB/MSW. If data are not normal then $F# does not have an $F$ distribution because MSB and MSW do not have the appropriate chi-squared distributions. So non-normality affects all three.

Comment: @BruceET in what way does non-normality affect the variance estimates please ? Is it consistent with the answer posted by Gordon Smyth ?

Comment: I am talking about **distribution theory** (hence reliability of P-value of F-statistic), @GordonSmith is talking about **unbiasedness** of estimators. //Consider exponential data instead of normal. In R, code `v = replicate(10^6, var(rexp(10))); mean(v)` returned $1.0006,$ suggesting unbiasedness, but a histogram of `9*v` is nowhere near compatible with $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=9).$ Also, `9*v` fails Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for that dist'n with P-value near $0.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unbiasedness of the within and between group mean squares depends only on second-moment assumptions and does not require normality. If the form of the ANOVA linear model is correct (first-moment assumption) and if the responses are uncorrelated and have equal variances (second-moment assumption) then the within and between group variance estimates are unbiased.

Comment: Thanks! And yes, linearity and independent observations are assumed.